# Web-based Contact Application that allows list forwarding

Tags: webapp-rec, email-forwarding, contacts

I've found with Constant Contact, iContact and MailChimp that if you use standard email forwarding to pass their email on, that any unsubscription will unsubscribe you, the sender, because they hardcode your email address in the email, instead of pulling it out of your mail settings (not sure if they even could if they wanted).

They both have a `forward to a friend` functionality, but it's limited to 5 or 20 names respectively, and they have to be typed in individually.

I want to be able to forward some of these mails to a large list.

Does anyone know of a good contact program that will allow someone to send emails out that can then be forwarded to a list (safely)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a management tool that takes your emails list and sends it out to a pre-selected list?

Or are you looking to use your list of contacts, saved in your email app, and send them emails without using a mailing client like iContact or Constant Contact?

If you're looking to forward the list of contacts, with more than 20 recepients, you can always use the CSV generated by an application or created by you and attach it as an email that has all its recipients as BCC.

Comment: I'm trying to find an email mailing client like Constant Contact that will either not force such an unfriendly unsubscribe feature, or it will have a more friendly forward feature.  I guess I just want a more flexible mailing client.

Comment: I would suggest MailChimp because my experience with it has been great, they have features that you can pick to use and they do have really specific features that you can add on to your account. I don't exactly have a list of the features, but I know there's a "forward-to-a-friend" feature which is included in the footer (http://www.mailchimp.com/features/full_list). 

Best of all, there's a free account type so you can definitely try it and upgrade it. (I'm not trying to sell mailchimp here, just found it easy to work with)